# How can I check two columns with two columns at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am trying to check if the combination of the values in columns [group] and [subgroup] are in a list of valid combinations.

When I just check one column like:

```
dataframe.loc[~(dataframe['group'].isin(validCombis.values.T[0].tolist())), 'myColumn'] = 'invalid'
```

it works fine.

But I get
*Type Error |
Key Error: 'subgroup'*

when trying the following:

```
dataframe.loc[~(dataframe['group']['subgroup'].isin(validCombis)), 'myColumn'] = 'invalid'
```

I need to check if both in combination are in **one row** in the list where I also have the two columns [group] and [subgroup].

***example:***

**validCombis**

> [group] [subgroup]
>
> ```
> 1       1
> 1       4
> 2       1
> 3       8
> ```

**dataframe**

> [group] [subgroup] [myColumn]
>
> ```
> 1       1        NaN
> 1       4        NaN
> 2       8        NaN
> 3       4        NaN
> ```

expected output after running some code

> [group] [subgroup] [myColumn]
>
> ```
> 1       1        NaN
> 1       4        NaN
> 2       8        invalid
> 3       4        invalid
> ```

Comment: if you want to check the sum `((dataframe['group'] + dataframe['subgroup']).isin(validCombis))` and if you want to check the combination `((dataframe['group'].astype(str) + dataframe['subgroup'].astype(str)).isin(validCombis))`

Comment: thanks a lot @J.Doe ! I just had do amend validCombis to validCombis['group']+validComis['subgroup'] in your code

Answer (score 0):

Based on @J.Doe 's comment, I found out that

```
dataframe.loc[~((dataframe['group'].astype(str) + dataframe['subgroup'].astype(str)).isin(validCombis['EK']+validCombis['EUK'])), 'myColumn'] = 'invalid'
```

works fine for me.